# Escaping DOI links in php - when esc_url() is not enough

Tags: php, html, escaping, href, doi

I am writing php code that generates html that contains links to documents via their [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). The links should point to `https://doi.org/` followed by the DOI of the document.

As the results is a url, I thought I could simply use php's `esc_url()` function like in

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url('https://doi.org/' . $doi)) . '">' . esc_url('https://doi.org/' . $doi)) . '</a>';
```

as this is what one is supposed to use in [text nodes, attribute nodes or anywhere else](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url). Unfortunately things apparenty aren't that easy...

The problem is that DOIs can contain all sorts of special characters that are apparently not handled correctly by `esc_url()`. A nice example of such a DOI is

`10.1002/(SICI)1521-3978(199806)46:4/5<493::AID-PROP493>3.0.CO;2-P`

which is supposed to link to

[https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1521-3978(199806)46:4/5<493::AID-PROP493>3.0.CO;2-P](https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1521-3978(199806)46:4/5%3C493::AID-PROP493%3E3.0.CO;2-P)

With `$doi` equal to this DOI the above code however produces a link that is displayed and links to `https://doi.org/10.1002/​(SICI)1521-3978(199806)46:4/​5493::AID-PROP4933.0.CO;2-P`.

This leads me to the question: If `esc_url()` is obviously not one-size-fits-all no-brained solution to escaping urls, then what should I use? For this case I can get the result I want with

```
esc_url(htmlspecialchars('https://doi.org/' . $doi))
```

but is this really **the right way™** of doing it? Does this have any other unwanted side effects? If not, then why does `esc_url()` not also escape `<` and `>`? Would `esc_html()` be better than `htmlspecialchars()`? If so, should I nest it into a `esc_url()`?

I am aware that there are many articles on escaping urls in php on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find one that addresses the issues of `<` and `>` signs.

Comment: When you [check the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3775), you see that this function removes any characters from the URL, that do not match the regular expression character class `[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\[\]\\x80-\\xff]` ( Introducing characters such a `<` and `>` into identifiers that are eventually supposed to become part of an HTTP URL is what I would call a rather dipshit decision on part of the DOI people to begin with though ...)

Comment: I fully agree on the "dipshit decision" part :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but I do know about DOIs and SICIs can be really annoying.

URL-encoding and HTML encoding are separate things, so it makes sense to think about them separately. You must escape the angle-brackets to make correct HTML. As for the URL-escaping, you should also do this because there are other characters that might break URLs (such as the `#` character, which also pops up from time to time).

So I would recommend:

```
'https://doi.org/' . htmlspecialcharacters(urlencode($doi))
```

Which will give you:

```
<a href="https://doi.org/10.1002%2F%28SICI%291521-3978%28199806%2946%3A4%2F5%3C493%3A%3AAID-PROP493%3E3.0.CO%3B2-P">Click here</a>
```

Note the order of function application, and the fact that you don't want to encode the `https://doi.org` resolver!

To the above "dipshit decision" comment... it's certainly inconvenient. But SICIs were around before DOIs and it's one of those annoying things we've had to live with ever since!

Comment: What is the argument for `urlencode()` over `rawurlencode()` and why is `htmlspecialcharacters()` necessary at all? Doesn't the output of  `urlencode()` only contain alphanumeric characters and + and - signs?

Comment: Oh, it looks like `urlencode` produces HTML-safe characters so `htmlspecialcharaters` isn't necessary. However, the specification suggests that you do do both: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: As for `urlencode` vs `rawurlencode`, from the PHP docs it looks like the only difference is treatment of the `~` character. However the two pages don't substantively reference each other.

Comment: What about the encoding of the doi in the link text (between <a href=""> and </a>?